# Add row at specific position in smartsheet using Smartsheet-API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smartsheet-api

```
Cell[] cellsA = new Cell[] { new Cell.AddCellBuilder(7960873114331012, true).Build(),
new Cell.AddCellBuilder(642523719853956, "New status").SetStrict(false).Build()
};

Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(true,null,null,null,null).SetCells(cellsA).Build();

smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(873476834787, new Row[] { rowA});
```

I want to add this row at a specific position like after 5th row.

[image]

Comment: if my answer below sufficiently addressed your question, can you please mark it as an "accepted" answer? Doing so will allow others to potentially benefit from the info in the future. Thanks!  (If my answer didn't resolve your issue, then please feel free to comment on my answer and I'll do my best to provide additional info.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Smartsheet C# SDK, `AddRowBuilder` is defined as follows:

[image]

When calling `AddRowBuilder`, you can specify the final two parameters (**siblingId** and **above**) to insert the new row directly above an existing row in the sheet. Note that **siblingId** should specify the GUID for that row -- not the row number that indicates its position in the sheet. For example, if you want to insert the new row directly above the row that has an ID of **7670198317672324**, your code would read like this:

`Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null,null,null,7670198317672324,true).SetCells(cellsA).Build();`